# text file to array of lose words (strings)

Tags: arrays, string, text, processing

i want to convert a text file to an array of strings. each string should be a word of the text. 
example:
hello i am thomas => {"hello","i","am","thomas"}

i tried the following but it doesnt seem to work.. and i dont get why.

```java
String words[];
void setup() {
    size(200, 200);

    String lines[] = loadStrings("text.txt");

    for (int i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {

         words = split(lines[i],"\\s+");
         lines[i].toLowerCase();
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < words.length; i++){
         print(words[i]+"====="); 
}

}
```

i get this:

Dat melden Duitse media. Conservatieve partijen haalden onlangs bij de verkiezingen de absolute meerderheid in het parlement. Zij hebben in het parlement wetsvoorstellen ingediend voor de hervorming van het constitutionele hof en de rechten van ambtenaren. In de praktijk zou dit volgens tegenstanders van de nieuwe wetten kunnen betekenen dat de regering niet meer gecontroleerd kan worden. De Europese Commissie heeft Polen voor de kerstdagen in een brandbrief nog gewaarschuwd voor uitholling van de rechtsstaat. Toetsing In de brief vroeg Europees vice-voorzitter Frans Timmermans de Poolse Senaat de wet niet aan te nemen of minstens te wachten met de uitvoering ervan tot alle kwesties in verband met de impact van de onafhankelijkheid en het functioneren van het Hof volledig zijn onderzocht. Polen heeft de Raad van Europa wel gevraagd de nieuwe wet te toetsen. Maar president Duda heeft die uitspraak dus niet afgewacht. Lachertje De conservatieve meerderheid baart ook de Poolse oud-president en Nobelprijswinnaar Lech Walesa zorgen. Hij riep vorige week op tot nieuwe verkiezingen in zijn land. Hij stelt dat de huidige politieke situatie in zijn land de democratie ondermijnt en Polen het lachertje van Europa maakt. Tienduizenden Polen hebben vorige week in meer dan twintig steden gedemonstreerd voor de democratie en tegen de conservatieve regering. In de hoofdstad Warschau verzamelden de demonstranten zich voor de parlementsgebouwen en scandeerden Nee tegen dictatuur. Ook in Berlijn, Londen en Brussel waren kleine demonstraties van Polen.=====

and i want:

array["Dat====","melden====","Duitse===="]

ans so on

when the text is printed i just get the text again...
any help would be greatly appriciated

Comment: could you be clearer in your question? what output are you getting? what do you want to get?

Comment: i hope this makes it more clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code doesn't make a ton of sense. You're reading in the lines from a text file, and then splitting each of those lines into an array called `words`. But you constantly overwrite the `words` variable, so really the for loop is just setting `words` to be the last line of the file. You then call `toLowerCase()` on the original line, but you don't actually do anything with that value.

You have to decide ahead of time whether your file will contain multiple lines, or just a single line. You seem to be mixing the logic for both, which doesn't make a ton of sense. You then have to actually store the split value in something.

Secondly, the `split()` function doesn't take a regular expression, it just takes a single character. Either give it a specific character, or use a different method for splitting your String values.

Assuming your input file will only have a single line, you might try something like this:

```java
String words[];

void setup() {
  size(200, 200);

  String lines[] = loadStrings("text.txt");

  //file only contains single line, so just get the first line
  words = split(lines[0], " ");

  for (int i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
    print(words[i]+"=====");
  }
}
```

More info can be found in [the Processing reference](https://processing.org/reference/split_.html).